# Computed or generated column in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Is there any option how to create a computed column in the CREATE TABLE statement? Something like generated column in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    ...,
    height_cm numeric,
    height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height_cm / 2.54) STORED
);
```

or computed column in T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
  ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
);
```

If there is no similar option, what could be the alternative please? My intention is to use these generated column in the materialized views without needs to compute them in MV create scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `MATERIALIZED` columns for storing computed values
   https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/#materialized
2. `ALIAS` columns to compute column values on the fly
   https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/#alias

Comment: thanks a lot, I went through these but was not able to find proper expression because of lack of examples. Finally it works like this `ts DateTime MATERIALIZED toDateTime(ts_ms)`